# VBA - Is it possible to declare a Variant array whose elements have the data types of different classes

Tags: vba, solidworks, solidworksapi

I would like to declare a variant array that contains different data types such as objects.

```
Dim faceObj As SldWorks.Face2

Dim selObject() As Variant
ReDim Preserve selObject(4)
' code that initializes faceObj is not included here
```

Now, selObject has 5 elements, that are of Empty data type.

I would like to change a first element datatype to be of a Face2 class.

```
Set selObject(0) = faceObj
```

While this works, array elements still have the Object datatype and therefore members of the objects are not offered by lint.

Apologies if I used wrong nomenclature as I don't understand properly OOP terminology.

I tried `ReDim selObject(i - 1) As SldWorks.Face2` but it says that can't change the datatype of array elements. I think I saw that in Variant it's possible to have the different datatypes but maybe my syntax is wrong.

**Edit:** Would it be better to rather use a structure array for this case?

Comment: Suppose it was possible to do what you are requesting: to have the IDE, at the point of *writing* code, understand that a loosely typed variable "now" (at *runtime*) holds a strongly typed object, and offer IntelliSense for you from that line onward. What would then happen if you had `If Something = 42 Then Set selObject(0) = faceObj Else Set selObject(0) = notFaceObjAtAll`? What kind of IntelliSense must then appear on the next line where you type `selObject(0).`?

Comment: If the selObject(0) was of faceObj type, then shouldn't it show faceObj's members?

Comment: How would the IDE know that `selObject(0)` was of `faceObj` type?

Comment: In the line `Set selObject(0) = faceObj `
However, selObject(0) still remains data type of object.

Comment: What about [such line as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978621/vba-is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variant-array-whose-elements-have-the-data-typ?noredirect=1#comment134005620_75978621) `If Something = 42 Then Set selObject(0) = faceObj Else Set selObject(0) = notFaceObjAtAll`, what type is in `selObject(0)` after that? What about if there is a `GoTo` statement above that causes the execution to jump over the `Set selObject(0) = faceObj` line, should the IDE still show the IntelliSense for `faceObj` even though it's not there? What if that `GoTo` is conditional?

Comment: If I assign different objects in each elements they remain as Object in selObject, but if I assign an integer to an element, it becomes an integer.

Comment: That is because `Variant\Object` exists, and so does `Variant\Integer`, but there is no finer division. Still, that has no relation to the IDE's inability to display different IntelliSense for the same variable that may contain different types of actual data at different points of time.

Comment: This is where you make the mistake "I would like to declare a variant array that contains different data types such as objects."  Oop is about structuring data appropriately, not mixing different data types ad lib.  Whaat is it you are trying to achieve by putting different datatypes in selObject.

Comment: It's clear now, thank you @GSerg.

I see, well, I wanted to put different objects in a same object array, and it works. However,  if I ask the data type of an element it will be "Object" instead of the actual class type. The issue with it, is that I can't see its members automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment section, it is not possible to redeclare elements to be of the different object class. It will still be the same Object data type.

Answer (score 0):

This is already implemented in the Solidworks API.

The `ISelectionManager` interface stores your current selections as an array of objects. You can use the built-in `GetSelectedObjectType(index)` to determine what you can cast the object as.

Using the `ISelectionManager.GetSelectedObject6(index, mark)` returns the selected object at the given index.

This example checks if the selection is a face and then casts it as the Face2 object successfully.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As ModelDoc2
    Dim swSelectionManager As SelectionMgr
    Dim swFace As Face2
    Dim swBody As Body2
    
    Dim selectionType As Integer
    Dim selection As Variant
    Dim selCount As Integer
    
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swSelectionManager = swModel.SelectionManager
    
    
    selCount = swSelectionManager.GetSelectedObjectCount2(-1)
    
    If selCount > 0 Then
        selectionType = swSelectionManager.GetSelectedObjectType(1)
        
        If selectionType = swSelectType_e.swSelFACES Then
            Set swFace = swSelectionManager.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
            'Now do what you want with the selection as Face2 object
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

However, if you're focused on using your own array, you can store items as `Entity` objects similar to the below example. Please note that this doesn't work with as many object types so it won't behave as nicely as the above method.

```
Dim myArray(0) As Variant
Set myArray(0) = swSelectionManager.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1) ' I'm just using this to fill my array

Dim swEntity As Entity

Set swEntity = myArray(0)
selectionType = swEntity.GetType ' cast as necessary after this
```